# Cannot find class SubscriberIdAndMessage

Tags: java, io, message, subscriber

I'm trying to use the SubscriberIdAndMessage from io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common, but when I try to import it, the compiler doesn't found it. However, it finds other classes from the io.eventuate.tram.consumer.common package, like MessageHandlerDecoratorChain or MessageHandlerDecorator. Do you know what might be the problem here?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried seing if the class SubscriberIdAndMessage is public?

If you put class SubscriberIdAndMessage, it is not the same as public class SubscriberIdAndMessage.

If this is not the issue, can you post a screenshot of the error?

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).